# AWS Lambda Function has occassional huge 10 minute gaps between initialization and invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a lambda setup which will occasionally take ten minutes between initialization and invocation, leading to severe performance degradation of the apps that depend on it. The lambda request is handled by API gateway, sent to the Lambda Context for our handler, and then sent to the lambda function itself. At this point it looks like the lambda is initialized, but will take anywhere from 1 to 10 minutes to invoke for the slow performing requests.

Provisioned concurrency seems to address the cold start problem, but we cant seem to find any indication that concurrency is the problem. Furthermore, we have no reason to believe this is a cold start problem, given that the request takes 10 minutes, versus 10 seconds. I have no idea where to start to address this problem. Can someone give me some tips?

[image]

Comment: Are you basing this on evidence in CloudWatch Logs or Metrics or something else? Can you add any detail that will clarify things here? Which programming language is being used and what does your Lambda function do during cold start (outside of the function handler)?

Comment: @jarmod added a picture here to show what I'm saying. I'll investigate precisely what's happening out of the function handler. It's kind of tough for a few reasons.